# Qt segmentation fault on function return

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a function that returns an iterator and I save the iterator in it.
This is the function that returns the iterator (where `building` is a enum) :

```
vector<building>::iterator it;

for (it = building.begin(); it != building.end(); ++it)
{
    if(it->getType() == type)
        return it;
}

return gebouwen.end();
```

Now when I do `it->isBusy();` Qt crashes and gives a segmentation fault.

The `isBusy` function is:

```
bool isBusy( void) const { return busy ; };
```

When I'm debugging the debugger in Qt stops at that line of code and gives:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.
Signal name: SIGSEGV
Signal meaning: Segmentation fault
```

I don't get why this simple function lets the system stop. I've rebooted because some people say it is because you're having memory leaks. But this still doesn't solve it.

Comment: Aside from other problems, consider returning "it" after such a for loop, and replace the inner "return it" with "break" so there is one point of return.

Comment: @ChristianRau `namespace nl { typedef en::buildings gebouwen; }` :p

Comment: if `building` is an enum, how do you call `.begin()` on it? Please clarify the question. Where is the vector declared? instead of making up some similar code, you should paste the actual code you use (or make sure that your compatible example compiles)

Comment: @StackedCrooked Nice idea, but they are variables. Maybe some kind of reference would work or better a wrapper function, to circumvent initialization issues.

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely that crash is caused by calling `isBusy ()` method on an object referenced by the "end" iterator returned by `gebouwen.end()`. There is no object associated with that special iterator, and so undefined behavior is triggered. You have to compare the iterator returned by that function against `gebouwen.end()` to make sure your object was found.

Also, having `void` C++ as a parameter list in C++ doesn't make any sense. In C, there is a difference between `void foo()` and `void foo (void)` - the first one implies that `foo` can accept any arguments, while the second one means it cannot accept any arguments. But this doesn't mean anything in C++ and so doesn't make sense while you have to type 4 more characters for no good reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the iterator of a local vector. The iterator gets copied, but the vector is destroyed after returning. So it crashes.

Instead, you probably want to return the item the iterator is currently pointing to: `*it`.

Comment: How do you know the vector is local?

Comment: You are right to ask, that was just an assumption. Still, there is no enough information in the question to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code really:

```
vector<building>::iterator foo(   vector<building> & gebouwen, Type type )
{
    vector<building>::iterator it;

    for (it = gebouwen.begin(); it != gebouwen.end(); ++it) {
        if(it->getType() == type) 
        return it;
    }
    return it;
}
```

Then either answers by Vlad or Tamas apply. You could be calling gebouwen.end()->isBusy() which causes SIGSEGV. Or calling that after gebouwen goes out of scope.